# Updating electron's update server value with an app update

Tags: github, electron, auto-update, electron-updater

I have a privately distributed app in electron, which uses my own git account (private repository) for update purposes.

I'm using GH_TOKEN.txt and this method;

```
autoUpdater.setFeedURL({
  provider: 'github',
  repo: '****',
  owner: '****',
  private: true,
  token: "****"
})
```

Now I would like to change this update server to another GitHub account, but I need to update the previous repo with this update so for the next update all the apps installed can use new one in the future.

I publish updates from the terminal, how can I publish a package to a server with a different update server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I published to a new GitHub account then downloaded files and uploaded to previous update server manually.

Although log output is like below not looking fantastic, but it seems to be working.

```
Found version 1.0.35 (url: APPNAME-Setup-1.0.35.exe)
New Update Available
Downloading update from APPNAME-Setup-1.0.35.exe
updater cache dir: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\APPNAME-updater
Cached update sha512 checksum doesn't match the latest available update. New update must be downloaded. 
Cached: **************************************************==, 
expected: **************************************************==. 
Directory for cached update will be cleaned
Download block maps (old: "https://api.github.com/repos/*******/APPNAME/releases/assets/23617985.blockmap", new: https://api.github.com/repos/*******/APPNAME/releases/assets/23617985.blockmap)
Cannot download differentially, fallback to full download: Error: Maximum allowed size is 50 MB
    at Object.responseHandler (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\APPNAME\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:241:26)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\APPNAME\resources\app.asar\node_modules\builder-util-runtime\out\httpExecutor.js:303:17)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:2510:12)
    at SimpleURLLoaderWrapper.emit (events.js:210:5)
New version 1.0.35 has been downloaded to C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\APPNAME-updater\pending\update.exe
```

Comment: This is an issue that both block maps are coming the same and hence it will fallback to the full download. I'm facing the same issue.